# Does creating a snapshot download the data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does it download the data when you call the snapshot or when you use it for something?  For example, would the code below just download the data from "pushedItem3" or would it download all of the data?

example data:

```
List-1: {
    pushedItem1: {data},
    pushedItem2: {data},
    pushedItem3: {data}
},
List-2: {
    pushedItem3: {data},
    pushedItem4: {data},
    pushedItem5: {data}
}
```

Below code searches each list for "pushedItem3".

```
ref.on("child_added", function(snap){ 
  var listID = snap.key();
  ref.child(listID).child("pushedItem3").on("value", function(shot){
    console.log(shot.val());
  }
}
```

This may not seem like much but to me it is the difference between the user downloading my entire firebase or just the related data.

Comment: As a note, you're not really calling the snapshop. A snapshot is a picture of the data at a particular database reference at a single point in time. It contains the data that's returned (from observing changes to a node, query etc). The amount of data that a snapshot holds depends on how you implement your code. Using Value will return all of the data at a specified node in a snapshot; e.g. all children, childrens children etc. It can be a BIG chunk of data. Using child_added however, will return each child, one at a time in the snapshot - much smaller chunks. A query can do the same thing

Comment: How would you query for "pushedItem3" in my example?

Comment: It would be better to structure the data differently. in each list (List-1, List-2 etc) each child could be a random node name generated by ChildByAutoId. Each of those children will have two child nodes: name and data. the name node will be name: "pushedItem1", name: "pushedItem2" etc and the data will contain data: {some data}. Then queries are simple: ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo("pushedItem3")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is downloaded by the time your callback is invoked. So in your code:

```
// nothing is downloaded yet
ref.on("child_added", function(snap){ 
  // the key and value of snap are downloaded
  var listID = snap.key();
  ref.child(listID).child("pushedItem3").on("value", function(shot){
    // the key and value of shot are downloaded
    console.log(shot.val());
  }
}
```

This is one of the reasons why the [Firebase documentation recommends against arbitrarily nesting data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-denormalizing-data):

> When we read a data node in our database, we also retrieve all of its children!

That is the warning from the documentation, but you should really read the entire page.

*Side note: you can easily monitor what data Firebase is retrieving by going to the Network tab of Chrome and checking the WebSockets traffic.*

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  Also thanks for the side note, I will find that very useful for my data management.